# Gem Install Error: NameError

Tags: ruby, rubygems, osx-lion, macos

I havent been been able to install any Gem since I updated to Mac OSX Lion.
Every time I try to install any gem the terminal window hangs.
I've uninstalled everything including ruby and reinstalled Ruby Gems but that didn't solve the problem.

After running:
gem install rails --debug 
I get this (only first lines shown):

```
Exception `NameError' at /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/command_manager.rb:177 - uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
Exception `LoadError' at /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36 - no such file to load -- psych
Exception `LoadError' at /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:62 - no such file to load -- psych
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 - File exists - /Users/marcogallen/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%80
Exception `Errno::EEXIST' at /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:243 - File exists - /Users/marcogallen/.gem/specs/gems.github.com%80
Exception `EOFError' at /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135 - end of file reached
Exception `EOFError' at /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:120 - end of file reached
Exception `EOFError' at /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1060 - end of file reached
```

GEM env gives this:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin11]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Users/[user]/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
     - http://gems.github.com
```

I'm totally clueless here, I hope some one can give me a hint or something.
MAC Book PRO running OSX Lion

Thanks
Marco

Answer (score 0):

Hey I had a really similar problem,

I upgraded to Ruby 1.9.2 using RVM [Click here!](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

It has its own way of managing Gems for each instance of Ruby and helped me understand where the gems were kept etc... If you have a read you should get there!

If it doesn't help I am sorry, but might be worth a try!

Comment: Thanks Charlie  sadly this didn't do the trick I made a fresh install for all Ruby and Gems.

Comment: thats kind of what I was suggesting! glad you got there